# DRF and Knox Authentication: Allow login for non-staff users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-knox

I have created a **Login API** which authenticates users from `django.contrib.auth.models.User`. I am using `DRF` and implementing a *token authentication* with `django-rest-knox` and so far so good.

The application I am developing is a bit complicated but I'm gonna use one of our sub-apps as an example. So we have a sub application called `jobnet` and the goal of this application is to ***allow people to register an account thru the website and be able to apply for available jobs in our company online***.

The application shall have separate login pages for 2 different types of users (i.e. staff users (the company's employees) and those online applicants. The process here is a online applicant will register for an account and that will be marked `is_staff=False`. Every time he logs in, he shall be redirected to his `non-staff dashboard` where he can *apply for jobs and manage applications*.

Once he gets officially hired, his account will be updated to `is_staff=True`. Now, he can either login via the applicant's login interface, or via the staff's login page. Either way, the system will detect that he is already a staff and will redirect him to the staff's dashboard instead.

I already have a logic (in mind) for redirecting users thru different views depending on their account configuration. My problem now is ***I have no idea how to allow non-staff users to be able to login*** in the first place using the authentication tools I am using (Django's User model and knox token authentication). Everytime I try to login a non-staff user, the response says ***"Invalid credentials..."***

I tried defining `has_permission(self, request)` method inside my LoginAPI class but to no avail.

**Here is my Login API source code:**

```
class LoginAPI(generics.GenericAPIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    permission_classes = ()
    authentication_classes = (knox.auth.TokenAuthentication,)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data
        allowed_modules = {}
        is_staff = False
        if user.is_staff:
            allowed_modules = set(Permission.objects.filter(group__user=user).values_list('codename', flat=True))
            is_staff = True
        return Response(
            {
                "user": UserSerializer(user, context=self.get_serializer_context()).data,
                "token": AuthToken.objects.create(user)[1],
                "authenticated": True,
                "staff": is_staff,
                "modules": allowed_modules
            }
        )
```

Comment: Which is your `authentication_classes` of `LoginAPI` ?

Comment: My `authentication_classes` will be `authentication_classes = (knox.auth.TokenAuthentication,)`.... I have updated my code above...

Comment: Which `knox` version are you using>?

Comment: I'm using `django-rest-knox v.4.1.0`

Comment: How do you sending the request to the LoginAPI? The header? credentials?

Comment: I am using `React` for my frontend... as per the code above, I am using the `GenericAPIView` and I am overriding the `post` method to do my custom way of logging in and generating knox-based authentication tokens when/where I need to...... my only concern is _how can I turn off checking of `is_staff` property_ of the `User` model in my login process... I just need to turn that off so I don't get the `Incorrect credentials` error and I can proceed to redirecting `non-staff` users to their respective dashboard view.

Comment: If you want a custom authentication, you should override the `TokenAuthentication` class. The error `Invalid credentials...` is raised within either from the auth class or permission class.

Comment: Apart from that, Your `LoginAPI` seems just a normal view which doesn't do any kind of authentication or permission schemes.

Comment: Okay WHAT THE ACTUAL FUDGE this is embarrassing but I just realized I have unchecked the `active` property of the account I was testing on so dumb... my authentication works just fine... sorry for the trouble...

Answer (score 0):

This inquiry is no longer relevant. I have just realized I have unchecked the `active` property of my test account in the admin portal that's why I was getting an error due to the ValidationError I have raised in my serializer. So so dumb... Nonetheless, code above works just as I want it and everything works fine in my authentication at the moment so far.

Although as per @ArakkalAbu pointed out in the comment above, I will take a look at my `LoginAPI` view and maybe actually pattern it the way **Knox** implements it on its `LoginView` since what I'm doing above is just overriding the `post` method, creating my custom login logic and just generating token via Knox's `Authtoken` model.

Thanks!